# "His head" or "their head"?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, grammatical-gender, singular-they

I was disappointed to see a favorite storybook from my childhood has been edited.  (*Harry, the Dirty Dog*; ISBN-13: 978-0064430098)  I distinctly remember the text written as follows:

> ...but everyone shook his head and said, "Oh, no, it couldn't be Harry."

I was taught that the male gender form takes precedence, when speaking several individuals of each gender.  However, the book was edited to read,

> ...but everyone shook <strike>his head</strike> **their head** and said, "Oh, no, it couldn't be Harry."

ARGH!  Please assure me that the original version and I are correct!  There are some other minor edits that have simply ruined the book for me.  (My linguistic snobbery helped, too.)

Comment: An interesting mix of [Is “everyone” singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225/), [Gender neutral pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/), and [“on their back” vs “on their backs”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/).

Comment: I like the Coe college discussion on [sexist language](http://www.public.coe.edu/~wcenter/handouts_nonsexist.php) which includes this point.

Comment: I move to add a "Policital-Correctness" tag!  This certainly falls dead in the sights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the edited version is incorrect.
It should be "but everyone shook **their** head" (singular head, for each individual. Unless you're dealing with a hydra :P)

The male dominance in pluralisation that you mentioned is still correct, but is avoided to not offend feminists, and will likely be phased out for the same reason.

Comment: I disagree that there is anything "incorrect" about the edited version. Language is how it is used, not how some logician abstractly thinks about it.

Comment: JORDAAN:  Please note I corrected the pluralization error.

Comment: The edited version uses **thier** not **his**, as a matter of fact, which contradicts with your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Everyone shook his head?  That might result into a headache.  Everyone shook their heads is correct.

Comment: There is a decent distinction being made here but my guess is that the downvote came from confusion about what, exactly, you were trying to point out.

Comment: Just for clarification, "Everyone shook his head".  That means that everyone shook his head.

Comment: <Wah wah wahhhh>  The trump of irony sounds!

Answer (score -1):

Better to recast the sentence.

> The audience found their seats.