# Noun following "everyone's"

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number, pronouns, possessive-pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “everyone” singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225/is-everyone-singular-or-plural)

Would the noun following "everyone's" be plural? For example:

> Everyone's heart sank.

Comment: I think that question is different. These seem more related to me: [“On their back” or “on their backs”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15322/on-their-back-or-on-their-backs), [“Only those who qualify will be awarded a certificate” vs. “only those who qualify will be awarded certificates”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6881/only-those-who-qualify-will-be-awarded-a-certificate-or-only-those-who-qualif)

Comment: I agree with @RegDwigнt. Another, more similar question (which is also mis-marked as a duplicate of "Is 'everyone' singular or plural?") is [Should “everyone's” be followed by a singular or plural noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256433)

Answer (score 3):

*Everyone* is a pronoun and means *every person* or *all people*. In your example *everyone's* denotes the possessive form of *everyone*. Remember that in AmE, it's always singular not plural. So the word following it should always be singular not plural, too. Here are a few examples:

> He got everyone's attention.
>
> Everyone needs him. (not *need*)
>
> Everyone likes him. (not *like*)
>
> Everyone's mom was there. (not moms)

That said, *everyone's* is also the abbreviated form of *everyone is*.

> Everyone's home for dinner *means* Everyone is home...

Comment: I'm curious as to why you qualify the pronoun being singular with "in AmE". Is there a variation of English where this is not the case?

Comment: @aaamos: I think it's not the case in BrE. Grammar Girl gives a reference to *Garner, B. Garner's Modern English Usage. Oxford: Oxford University Press. 2003, pp. 320-1.* and says: *"if you’re in Britain, you don’t have to worry so much about everyone and everybody because sometimes they’re considered plural."* http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/indefinite-pronouns.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reference you quote is about the usage of "everyone" with a _plural pronoun_ rather than with a _plural verb_ (e.g. "everyone has _their_ own"), but the sentence isn't exactly well-phrased and somewhat misleading (usage of "everyone" with a singular verb and a plural pronoun doesn't imply that "everyone" is considered plural). I'll refrain from commenting on the name of the author or the domain of said reference. ;-) Happy to be proven wrong, but I'd still say that "everyone" is considered to be a singular noun in British and Australian English as well.

Comment: @aaamos: I am not sure. But do you think it would be better to remove the "in AmE" part from my answer and make it plain English?

Comment: Personally, I'd leave it out and see if anyone corrects it, but as I'm not 100% certain, I'm just as happy if you decide to leave it. :-)

Comment: *Their* in *everyone has their own* isn't a plural pronoun. The sentence is equivalent to *everyone has his or her own* and illustrates the regular use of *they* as a singular pronoun in informal speech to avoid the pedantic-sounding *he or she*.

Comment: @boargules: You are of course correct, but this was in reply to a reference from another site, and had I not used the phrase "plural pronoun" in this instance, it would have served to confuse matters even further.

Comment: No citation to support claim.