# In the sentence 'This means everyone should have their turn to say something.' , why is the noun not used in plural?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I am preparing for an exam, and came across the sentence below.

'This means everyone should have their turn to say something'

And I wondered why this sentence has no grammatical errors. 
Isn't the noun 'turn' countable? hence should be used in the plural form or should have the indefinitive article 'a'?

For me 'everyone should have a turn to say something' sounds correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you’ve transcribed it incorrectly, it is wrong.  It needs to be “*... have **a** turn*...”

Comment: That's what I thought, too. Thanks!

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/everyone-everybody-everything-everywhere

Comment: Related/ Possible Duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/225/14666 This Q was asked more than once before here.

Comment: If you feel ''This means everyone should have his turn to say something" when speaking about 20 men say is correct, you need to look up "singular 'they' ". If you think 20 men say should need 'their turns', you can look up [Do you pluralize the singular possessions of individual members of a plural group?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/213080/do-you-pluralize-the-singular-possessions-of-individual-members-of-a-plural-grou).

Comment: Ah in that sense, it looks correct. Whoa I've known that we use everyone as a singular noun, but didn't think of that affects what comes as objects. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

*have-turn* is understood as a compound verb by whoever says this, if they don't just blindly repeat it, however, it's neither awfully frequent nor current overall. *To take turns* is much more frequent.

The lack of plural can be explained as analogy to *take part*.